# What is the best method for adding fractions?

Tags: c++, math, optimization, fractions

What is the most efficient method when adding fractions and subsequently reducing by dividing by the GCD?

Method 1:

```
a/b + c/d = (a*d + b*c) / b*d
```

Method 2:

```
x = lcm(b, d)
[a * (x / b) + c * (x / d)] / x
```

Comment: Method 2 looks good if product and additions don't overflow

Comment: It depends on the data structures used and the algorithms already implemented. If the internal representation is just a pair of `int` or `unsigned int`, just adding and reducing afterwards might be best.

Comment: I would totally second Mohit Jain, i think overflow might be of more concern than efficiency.

Comment: Are you running on a fix-point processor (no HW support for floating-point operations)? Otherwise, `a/b+c/d` yields the minimum number of operations (3).

Comment: Hmm.  I assume you are working with a rational data type of some kind?  Or are those supposed to be `double`/`float`s?

Answer (score 2):

Method 3:

```
x = gcd(b, d)
[a * (d/x) + c * (b/x)] / (b/x*d)
```

which minimizes the chance of overflow by reducing the magnitude of the values in the calculation.

Overflow checks need still be done.

Even with infinite precision values, the above may reduce allocation costs (bigger numbers use more memory).

Oh, and profile,